# Dummy Firebase Analytics events for tests

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am setting up Firebase v4 for analytics but for now I have no idea of how events and param are shown in the Firebase console.

Thus, I'd like to implement a dummy `Event` with some dummy `Params`, so I could play around with my app (in DEBUG mode if possible) and see the result in the console.

I know you can do this with Facebook SDK but I couldn't find how to with Firebase.

How can I do so without polluting my console with dummies ?

Quick links (which of course I searched through) : [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics)

CONFIG : Android Studio 3.0, Firebase setup by the AS assistant

Comment: You can just start logging some events. See the [Analytics Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/analytics) for an example. Instructions for debug mode are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. But you can track any event by using the `FirebaseAnalytics` class.

```
FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "ID");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "NAME");
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "image");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

Some things to note
--Any params attached to a custom event are considered custom params. Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#log_events

If it is a matter of not polluting your **debug** analytics (analytics tracked while developing) and **production** analytics (analytics tracked once released) this can be managed with a variety of ways, but I suggest using `productFlavors` to your advantage.

1) Specify a flavor dimension

```
// specifies a flavor dimension
flavorDimensions "app"
```

2) Add productFlavors to your project gradle file

```
// flavor implementation propelled by request for multiple environments on Crashlytics
    productFlavors {
        standard {
            applicationId '<app package name>'
            dimension "app"
        }
    }
```

3) Include suffix to build types

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        // debuggable
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        // its up to you and how you want to setup your flavors, but you can add applicationIdSuffix '.prod'
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Comment: Yes pollution is exactly the point ! Could you be kind enough to explain a little more how to use Flavors for this task ?